# Get notification of Wifi availability for Wifi enabled device

Tags: ios, wifi, cfnetwork

I have OBD2 device adapter which supports Wifi. Now I want to get notification about Wifi with OBD2 device is available so I can start talking to that device and read data and Wifi with OBD2 device is not available.

When device is connected to OBD2 Port,wifi is broadcasting. I have used sample code of Reachability class. But I can't get proper notification.

I tried with SimplePingHelper code. It works fine with Main thread but it not runs with background thread. [SimplePingHelper Source code](https://github.com/chrishulbert/SimplePingHelper)

SimplePingHelper code actually uses SimplePing sample code from Apple.
[SimplePing Code By Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Listings/SimplePing_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-SimplePing_h-DontLinkElementID_4)

Can you help me in this code that it works with background thread Or What are other ways I can check to get this notification ?

Answer (score 1):

`Use Apple's default reachability class:

Download reachability project from [This link](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Copy Reachability.h and Reachability.m file in your project.

And set this method in Application delegate file.

-(void)initializeRechabilityObeserver
{ 
    //Change the host name here to change the server your monitoring
    hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com http://www.apple.com"];
    [hostReach startNotifier];
    //[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: hostReach];

```
internetReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[internetReach startNotifier];
//[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: internetReach];

wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] ;
[wifiReach startNotifier];
//[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: wifiReach];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use Apple's default reachability class:

Download reachability project from [This link](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Copy Reachability.h and Reachability.m file in your project.

And set this method in Application delegate file.

```
-(void)initializeRechabilityObeserver
{ 
    //Change the host name here to change the server your monitoring
    hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com <http://www.apple.com>"];
    [hostReach startNotifier];
    //[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: hostReach];

    internetReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetReach startNotifier];
    //[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: internetReach];

    wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] ;
    [wifiReach startNotifier];
    //[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: wifiReach];    
}
```

For getting Reachability change notification use below code:

Add this notification method in Application didFinishLaunching

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
    internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] ;
    [internetReachable startNotifier];
}
```

and also add this method:

```
- (void)reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
{
    NSLog(@"Reachability changed");
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
   [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: curReach];
}
```

Comment: I have used the same code as you have mentioned..But it's not working with Wifi Enabled Device

Answer (score 0):

Reachability only detect the network availability of your iOS device itself.
In addition, Apple doesn't allow apps to do any Wi-Fi scans, so there is no public API to do so.

Is your OBD2 device adapter connected to iOS device physically by cable or by local Wi-Fi?
I think you should focus on how to communicate to the external OBD2 device in iOS.